# Condicionales lógicos múltiples. Aligerar código

Tags: python-3.x, condiciones

recién empiezo a programar, con lo que puede que la pregunta sea muy básica, pero creo que debe poder hacerse de alguna manera fácil pero no lo encuentro.
Estoy haciendo un condicional multiple en el que se entra un número y devuelve un día de la semana (sí, así de pez estoy todavía). El programa funciona correctamente, incluso que sea repetitivo hasta que ponga un 0 para salir.
El problema es que pongo un condicional:

```
 if dia == 1 or dia == 2 or dia == 3 or dia == 4 or dia == 5 or dia == 6 or dia == 7:

      print(f"El dia indicado es {diasemana}")
 else:
      print("El dia entrado es incorrecto")
```

Hasta aqui funciona, pero veo que si algún día tengo que comparar 100 resultados me puedo morir de tantos "or". Entonces he probado  a poner:

```
 if dia == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]:
```

Pero no funciona.
Creo que debe poder hacerse fácil, pero no se como.

Gracias y perdonad mi ignorancia.

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si vas a comparar enteros consecutivos (rango) es mucho más simple y eficiente usar un intervalo en el condicional:

```
dia = input("Ingrese el número del día: ")
try:
    dia = int(dia)
except ValueError:
    print("El dia entrado es incorrecto")
else:
    if 1 <= dia <= 7:
        print(f"Ha ingresado {dia}")
    else:
        print("El dia entrado es incorrecto")
```

Si vas a usar una lista u otro contenedor usa el operador de pertenencia `in`:

```
if dia in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]:
```

La comparación `dia == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` siempre va a ser `False` , `dia` es un entero y se compara con una lista, son dos objetos distintos no asimilables entre si como si lo es `int` y `float` por ejemplo (`2 == 2.0`).

Incluso podrías substituir la lista por `range`:

```
if dia in range(1, 8):
```

El operador `in` sería similar a hacer:

```
for n in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]:
    if n == dia:
        print("Encontrado")
        break  # Romper ciclo, short-circuit
else:
    print("No encontrado")
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes Hacerlo con un for y if que te recorra el arreglo :) no se python pero la logica es lo mismo

```
//Console.ReadLine y WriteLine serian tu print

           int[] dia = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };


            for (int i = 0; i < dia.Length; i++)
            {
                if (dia[i] == int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())){

                    //dos formas

                    //La primera
                    Console.WriteLine(dia[i]);
                    //La segunda
                    Console.WriteLine("Esta el numero");
                   }
        }
```

Comment: Procura responder en el lenguaje asociado, involucrar otro puede llevar al OP a confusiones